# how to block access cpanel login cpanel.mydomain.com

Tags: cpanel

hi there i install Cpanel on my VPS now i want people can't access my Cpanel login page i will block all port and domain/cpanel access but i can't do block cpanel.mydomain.com

when i hit cpanel.mydomain.com it show Cpanel login page i need to disable or block this

i already tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cpanel [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

chatgpt say i can do this using .htaccess

but not work

please let me know how to do this